# How to run 'aws s3 sync .\FOLDER_PATH s3://BUCKET_NAME/SUB_DIRECTORY' from a PowerShell script in Win 10 pro?

Tags: powershell, amazon-s3

I want to track a Win-10 pro folder to `sync` with a backup `AWS S3 bucket`, every time a file is created in that folder. I have a PowerShell that is waching Create, Delete, Rename events in a `C:\source` folder. Following is the code:

```
# create an array that tracks each file
$global:files = @()
# where we will move the file once it is free
$destination = "C:\destination"

$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\source"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

$action = {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $logline = "$(Get-Date -f o), $changeType, $path"
    Add-content "C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Documentos\log.txt" -value $logline
    Write-Host $logline

    if($changeType -eq "Renamed" -and $path.Split(".")[-1] -ne "crdownload") {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Found the file we need! $path"
        Add-content "C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Documentos\log.txt" -value "Found the file we need! $path"
        $global:files += $path
    }
    if($changeType -eq "Created" ) {
        cmd.exe /c "aws s3 sync .\source s3://backuptesttdxckf"
        Add-content "C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Documentos\log.txt" -value "Synced to S3! $path"
        $global:files += $path
    }
}    

Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action

while ($true) {

    # if there are any files to process, check if they are locked
    if($global:files) {

        $global:files | % {

            $file = $_
            # assume the file is locked
            $fileFree = $false

            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Checking if the file is locked... ($file)"
            Add-content "C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Documentos\log.txt" -value "Checking if the file is locked... ($_)"

            # true  = file is free
            # false = file is locked
            try {
                [IO.File]::OpenWrite($file).close();Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "File is free! ($file)"
                Add-content "C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Documentos\log.txt" -value "File is free! ($file)"
                $fileFree = $true
            }
            catch {
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "File is Locked ($file)"
                Add-content "C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Documentos\log.txt" -value "File is Locked ($file)"
            }

            if($fileFree) {

                # do what we want with the file, since it is free
                Move-Item $file $destination
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Moving file ($file)"
                Add-content "C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Documentos\log.txt" -value "Moving file ($file)"

                # make sure we don't progress until the file has finished moving
                while(Test-Path $file) {
                    Sleep 1
                }

                # remove the current file from the array
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Done processing this file. ($file)"
                Add-content "C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Documentos\log.txt" -value "Done processing this file. ($file)"
                $global:files = $global:files | ? { $_ -ne $file }
            }

        }
    }

    sleep 2
}
```

This code updates a log.txt for any action of Create, Delete or Rename files. If I remove the `if($changeType -eq "Created" )` portion it works well (create the log). If I add the `if($changeType -eq "Created" )` portion it completely breaks, no logs no AWS sync.

This is my first time with PowerShell and I don't know what is going wrong in that if condition

```
if($changeType -eq "Created") {
    cmd.exe /c "aws s3 sync .\source s3://backuptesttdxckf"
    Add-content "C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Documentos\log.txt" -value "Synced to S3! $path"
    $global:files += $path
}
```

If I run `aws s3 sync .\source s3://backuptesttdxckf` in the cmd terminal it works but here it is not working. No error message. Nothing happens. No clues.

Any Idea how to solve this?

Comment: Why ar you attempting to run ```aws s3 sync .\source s3://backuptesttdxckf``` in `cmd.exe`? What is wrong with running it in `powershell.exe` itself?

Comment: display change type : Write-Host $changeType.GetType()  The type is not a string so remove the double quotes.

Comment: @jdweng,  `$changeType` is an enum value of type `System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes`. Comparing such a to a _string_ does work in PowerShell, because the string is automatically converted to the corresponding enum value. Verify with `[System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes]::Created -eq 'Created'`, which yields `$true`. In other words: Your comment isn't relevant to this question. Moreover, it suggests a solution (removing double quotes around `"Created"`) that will _syntactically break_ the code.

Comment: If I remove the `if($changeType -eq "Created")` portion, the code works well with double quotes. The point here is the code goes inside the if condition but does not sync with AWS S3. The portion that is causing the issue is `cmd.exe /c "aws s3 sync .\source s3://backuptesttdxckf"`

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was a bad path in the `Source path`. Replaced `.\source` by `C:\source` inside `if($changeType -eq "Created" )...` condition and it is working. Also removed `$global:files += $path` to avoid the file to be deleted after creation.

Following is the full functional code:

```
# create an array that tracks each file
$global:files = @()
# where we will move the file once it is free
$destination = "C:\destination"

$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\source"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

$action = {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $logline = "$(Get-Date -f o), $changeType, $path"
    Add-content "C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Documentos\log.txt" -value $logline
    Write-Host $logline

    if($changeType -eq "Renamed" -and $path.Split(".")[-1] -ne "crdownload") {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Found the file we need! $path"
        Add-content "C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Documentos\log.txt" -value "Found the file we need! $path"
        $global:files += $path
    }
    if($changeType -eq "Created" ) {
        cmd.exe /c "aws s3 sync C:\source s3://backuptesttdxckf"
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "synced with s3... ($file)"
        Add-content "C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Documentos\log.txt" -value "Synced to S3! $path"
    }
}    

Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action

while ($true) {

    # if there are any files to process, check if they are locked
    if($global:files) {

        $global:files | % {

            $file = $_
            # assume the file is locked
            $fileFree = $false

            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Checking if the file is locked... ($file)"
            Add-content "C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Documentos\log.txt" -value "Checking if the file is locked... ($_)"

            # true  = file is free
            # false = file is locked
            try {
                [IO.File]::OpenWrite($file).close();Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "File is free! ($file)"
                Add-content "C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Documentos\log.txt" -value "File is free! ($file)"
                $fileFree = $true
            }
            catch {
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "File is Locked ($file)"
                Add-content "C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Documentos\log.txt" -value "File is Locked ($file)"
            }

            if($fileFree) {

                # do what we want with the file, since it is free
                Move-Item $file $destination
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Moving file ($file)"
                Add-content "C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Documentos\log.txt" -value "Moving file ($file)"

                # make sure we don't progress until the file has finished moving
                while(Test-Path $file) {
                    Sleep 1
                }

                # remove the current file from the array
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Done processing this file. ($file)"
                Add-content "C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Documentos\log.txt" -value "Done processing this file. ($file)"
                $global:files = $global:files | ? { $_ -ne $file }
            }

        }
    }

    sleep 2
}
```